# Refresh meta tag's content change in html from js not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, meta

I am modifying content of meta refresh tag but when page is refreshing its not redireting on new Url.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="refreshMeta" http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=new1.html">

<script>
    $('meta[name=refreshMeta]').attr('content','5;url=new2.html');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Page refresh in every 5 seconds.
</body>
</html>
```

I can see content changed in console but while page is refreshing its showing new1.html instead of new2.html (working fine in chrome but problem in firefox).

please suggest me how to override the refresh meta tag's content using jquery.

thanks in advance

Comment: lol have you heard about windows.location ??

Comment: I don't want to use window.location,  want to achive it using meta refresh tag in firefox.

Comment: best option would be to create it server side then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `windows.location` to redirect from a page to another, use timeout functions to achieve the 5 seconds delay

```
window.location = "new2.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Doctype ones

Below one should will resolve your issues

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3. org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`<